# What are family-friendly places to visit in Hiroshima with young kids?

Tags: japan, children, family

I'm planning a trip to Kyushu (from Osaka) and may be passing by Hiroshima for one night. We're considering a stop there, but I am wondering what I can take a couple of toddlers (4 and 2) in November.

I only know of the Peace Dome and Miyajima, but I'm not sure of:

- How long I need at the peace dome?
- Is Miyajima a whole day trip and is it worth seeing in early November?
- What other things are interesting in Hiroshima
- How long public transportation takes

Context: I'm interested in both things to do that are interesting to both Japanese and foreigners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How long I need at the peace dome?

It's just the ruin of a relatively small building to look at from the outside. The whole park, including the [Sadako Sasaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadako_Sasaki) memorial, takes an hour, tops. There's a museum that probably takes more time, but probably not a good place to take toddlers to.

> Is Miyajima a whole day trip

With toddlers, it's at least a half day trip.

> and is it worth seeing in early November?

Very much so! In fact, that would be one of the best times to visit, as the trees in [maple valley](http://www.japan-guide.com/blog/koyo13/131121.html) should be in full fall splendor. And the kids will love the [tame deer and the monekys](http://www.miyajima.or.jp/english/nature/nature_animal.html).

[image]

> What other things are interesting in Hiroshima

There's a [castle](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e3402.html) (a reconstruction, of course) with a museum inside and a viewing platform on top.

> How long public transportation takes

From the city center to Miyajima it's about 45 minutes (including the ferry ride), otherwise everything is in walking distance.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend talking a toddler to any of the museums inside the peace park. My group (which were all mid-20s males) were pretty shaken by some of the stuff, and there were things that I wouldn't want to show a child just yet (the effects of radiation on people, there's a display that has mannequins of what people looked like post detonation), and maybe a few things that can shake you too. If you do go to the peace park (I still highly recommend, it is beautiful!) try to go on a sunny day, as I went on a cloudy rainy day and it just made everything even more melancholy.

If there are teams still playing, you can go to a few stadiums (We stayed near the zoom zoom stadium, but couldn't go since we were only there for a day) and maybe catch a game.

Comment: Melancholy might actually be the feeling one looks for when visiting such a place. :)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. As it turned out, our plans changed and we couldn't make Hiroshima, unfortunately. I was debating taking small children there. As a side point: I would think that the amount of violence that many kids are shown by some parents' entertainment choices would make those images tame in comparison.